# WindowsVideoMedia error in Resources in unity build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having problems with the build of my unity project. I'm trying to play 360 videos using VideoPlayer, so far I haven't had any problem, but now I'm having this problem when building. I have tested in Unity editor, MacOS and Oculus Quest, and it works perfectly, it only fails in the Windows build:

```
WindowsVideoMedia error 0x80004005 while reading C:/Proyectos/build/vrteacher/VRTeacher 
Desktop_Data/sharedassets2.resource

Context: CreateObjectFromByteStream
Error details: Error no especificado

Track types:

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/Video/Public/Media/WindowsMedia/WindowsVideoMedia.cpp Line: 3590)
```